# global name self is not defined python

Tags: python, pygame

Hey guys I don't know what is going wrong with my python/pygame game it's keeps giving me this error when try to run it with the IDLE

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/code/gmaes/game/adad.py", line 102, in <module>
    Game().main(screen)
  File "C:/code/gmaes/game/adad.py", line 95, in main
    self.tilemap.update(dt/1000.,self)
  File "C:/code/gmaes/game\tmx.py", line 689, in update
    layer.update(dt, *args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 399, in update
    for s in self.sprites(): s.update(*args)
  File "C:/code/gmaes/game/adad.py", line 36, in update
    if self.resting and key[pygame.K_SPCAE]:
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

I don't know why im getting this error and i have never gotten this problem before, I was hoping you guys and girls could help. Here is my full code, take a look and leave your thoughts

## Main Run File For Python game !python/pygame

```
import pygame
import tmx

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,location,frames,*groups):
        super(Player,self).__init__(*groups)
        self.frame = 0
        self.frames = frames
        self.image = self.frames[self.frame]
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(location,self.image.get_size())
        self.resting = False
        self.dy = 0
        self.is_dead = False
        self.direction = 1
    def update(slef,dt,game):
        last = slef.rect.copy
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.rect -= 300 * dt
                self.direction = -1
                self.frame = self.frame
                self.frame += 1
                self.image = self.frames[frame]
                if self.frame > 2:
                        self.frame = 0
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.rect -= 300 * dt
                self.direction = 1
                self.frame = self.frame
                slef.frame += 1
                self.image = self.frames[frame]
        if slef.frame > 2:
                self.frame = 0

        if self.resting and key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                self.dy = -500
        self.dy = min(400,self.dy + 40)
        self.rect.y += self.dy  * dt

        new = self.rect
        self.resting = False

        for cell in game.tilemap.layers['triggers'].collide(new,'blockers'):
            blockers = cell['blockers']
            if 'l' in blockers and last.right <= cell.left and new.right > cell.left:
                new.right = cell.left
            if 'r' in blockers and last.left >= cell.right and new.left < cell.right:
                new.left = cell.right
            if 't' in blockers and last.bottom <= cell.top and new.bottom > cell.top:
                self.resting = True
                new.bottom = cell.top
                self.dy = 0
            if 'b' in blockers and last.top >= cell.bottom and new.top < cell.bottom:
                new.top = cell.bottom
                self.dy = 0
            game.tilemap.set_focus(new.x,new.y)


class sprite_system(object):
    def slice_sheet(self,sprite_sheet,sprite_start_x,sprite_start_y,sprite_size_x,sprite_size_y,sheet_frames):
        frame = []
        sheet_start = 1
        frame_pos = 0
        sprite_start_x_base = sprite_size_x
        while sheet_start <= sheet_frames:
            sheet = sprite_sheet
            sheet.set_clip(pygame.Rect(sprite_start_x,sprite_start_y,sprite_size_x,sprite_size_y))
            sprite_clip = sheet.subsurface(sheet.get_clip())
            frame.append(sprite_clip)
            sprite_start_x += sprite_start_x_base
            sheet_start += 1
        return frame


class Game(object):
    def main(self,screen):
        sprite = pygame.image.load('test.png')
        frames = sprite_system().slice_sheet(sprite,0,0,64,64,4)
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.tilemap = tmx.load('lvl1.tmx',screen.get_size())
        self.sprites = tmx.SpriteLayer()
        start_cell = self.tilemap.layers['triggers'].find('player')[0]
        self.player = Player((start_cell.px,start_cell.py),frames,self.sprites)
        self.tilemap.layers.append(self.sprites)

        while 1:
            dt = clock.tick(30)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        return
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        return
            self.tilemap.update(dt/1000.,self)
            self.tilemap.draw(screen)
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((854,480))
    Game().main(screen)
```

oh and here is the snipet of code that is failing

```
if self.resting and key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        self.dy = -500
        self.dy = min(400,self.dy + 40)
        self.rect.y += self.dy  * dt

        new = self.rect
        self.resting = False
```

Comment: Interestingly you seem to also have a typo in your traceback .. `K_SPCAE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function `update()`, you forgot to add `self` as your first argument.

Or it's just a typo of `slef`

Comment: this might be a stretch but there is another error that im getting with AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'right'
with the line 
 if 'l' in blockers and last.right <= cell.left and new.right > cell.left:
i think it has something to do with the tmx lib im using but really don't know enough about it to be sure what to do. do you know where i should start looking

Comment: @IdecEddy `last = self.rect.copy` should this be `last = self.rect.copy()` ? I don't know anything about pygame, sorry, but according to your traceback, it seems you just mentioned the function and forgot to call it

Comment: thank you so much I need to keep practicing at writing code those small typos really mess you up if your not paying attention all is working in the code now :D